# HTTPS PHP large XML payload does not reach the client with echo

Tags: php, ios, xml, ssl, https

Our web service is experiencing a big issue with some clients. The web service is a PHP script under SSL which uses GET parameters to configure multiple heavy queries on a MySQL database and returns an XML payload. The payload is only 1 MB but processing is very complex and takes about 5-6 minutes to finish. Clients are iPad running a specific application. Sometimes, and on some networks, the client does not receive the payload and keep waiting until timeout. We started logging everything on our server. A normal response_ssl reports about 290 seconds to serve the payload, but when the issue occurs we can see 900 seconds for the same payload. However, even after 900 seconds the client does not receive the payload.

Inside the PHP script, we have some debug logging like this:

```
[perform long-time operation]
[create XML dom]
$xmlPayload=$dom->saveXML();
LOG: "Start print XML"
echo $xmlPayload;
LOG: "End print XML"
```

When the issue occurs, we can find the line "Start print XML" in the log file, but the **"End print XML" is never appended**. It seems that php scripts quits or freezes. We tried to activate log_error in PHP and no notice, warning nor error is logged!

We can't access the clients that are experiencing the issue and on our clients never occurs (we tried in every scenario). There's no common pattern on the clients affected (different networks, different iOS versions, different iPad versions and so on). We would like to know how to debug this annoying problem! Any ideas on how to **debug that "freezed" echo**? Thank you!

Comment: `$xmlPayload=$dom->saveXML;` - I'm going to guess you wanted `$xmlPayload=$dom->saveXML();`. Note the `()` added at the end.

Comment: @N.B. Sorry it was a typing mistake. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

I can't fully answer your question because from your error description it is not really clear what happens.

If PHP crashes, there normally should be an error message which is most often logged then (as you have error logging enabled). An exception to this would be a segmentation fault or if the operating system kills the process w/o notifying it (e.g. some hard limit).

Even though I can't tell you exactly what goes wrong, you can spare some resources (which could help if indeed there is some hard limit). You can save resources by "saving" the XML document to standard output directly. This spares you to store the XML into a variable only to echo it later on:

```
[perform long-time operation]
[create XML dom]
LOG: "Start print XML"
$dom->save('php://output');
LOG: "End print XML"
```

This is just making use of `DOMDocument::save` to save to a "file" and the file is indeed a PHP stream to standard output (which is the same target as echo uses), namely `php://output`.

Hopefully this little change will make it work or otherwise the information given or the change it introduce will reveal more information for you to tackle the problem.